# code is invalid under python 2.6 but fine in 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, python-2.6

can someone help me translate some python 2.7 syntax to python 2.6 please (kinda stuck on 2.6 due to redhat dependencies)

so i have a simple function to construct a tree:

```
def tree(): return defaultdict(tree)
```

and of course i would like to display the tree in some way. under python 2.7 i can use:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 17 2012, 03:00:49)
[GCC 4.4.6 [TWW]] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def dicts(t): return {k: dicts(t[k]) for k in t}
...
>>>
```

all good... but under 2.6 i get the following error:

```
$ /usr/bin/python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep  4 2013, 07:46:00)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def dicts(t): return {k: dicts(t[k]) for k in t}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def dicts(t): return {k: dicts(t[k]) for k in t}
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how can i rewrite the code:

```
def dicts(t): return {k: dicts(t[k]) for k in t}
```

so that i can use it under python 2.6?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to replace the dict comprehension with the `dict()` being passed a generator expression. ie.

```
def dicts(t): return dict((k, dicts(t[k])) for k in t)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dicts(t):
    d = {}
    for k in t:
        d[k] = dicts(t[k])
    return d
```